# How to fetch colormind API with axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I was trying to use Axios to fetch Colormind API. But the result showed Network Error. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

```js
const url = "http://colormind.io/api/";
const data = {
    model: "default"
  }

const reloadBtn = document.querySelector('.reload-btn')


async function getColors(){
  axios.post(url,data)
  .then(response => {
    const palette = response.data.result;
     console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  
}


reloadBtn.addEventListener('click',async (e) => {
  await getColors();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button class="reload-btn">click</button>
```

Comment: The error net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID suggests that there is an issue with the SSL certificate of the colormind.io API server. This error occurs when the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the client.

Comment: "*the result showed Network Error.*" - which error?

Comment: @Bergi I paste the error message on the post, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Please add [error messages as formatted text, not as a painting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! Also, what is the network error shown in the devtools?

Comment: The error message exposed to JavaScript is highly sanitised to avoid leaking data across origins.You need to look at the console and network tab to see the real error message.

Comment: You will always have issues if you try to load http from https and your API does not have a valid cert

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the Colormind API using Axios, you need to ensure that you are making the API request correctly and handling any potential errors. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to fetch the API successfully:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = "http://colormind.io/api/";
const data = {
  model: "default"
};

const reloadBtn = document.querySelector('.reload-btn');

async function getColors() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, data);
    const palette = response.data.result;
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

reloadBtn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
  await getColors();
});
```

In the modified code:

First, ensure that you have installed Axios by running npm install axios or including it in your project using another method.

Import the Axios library using const axios = require('axios'); or using an import statement if you're using ES modules.

Use an async/await approach inside the getColors() function to make the asynchronous API request with Axios. This way, you can directly use the await keyword to wait for the response instead of chaining promises with .then() and .catch().

Wrap the API request within a try/catch block to handle any potential errors. If an error occurs, it will be caught in the catch block, and you can log the error to the console.

Make sure you have a stable internet connection and that the Colormind API is accessible from your network. If you still encounter a network error, make sure to check your network settings and firewall configurations to ensure that the API request is not blocked.

Remember to replace the click line with the appropriate HTML in your application.

With these modifications, you should be able to fetch the Colormind API successfully using Axios.